# Kontakt sdk not detecting Radius beacon

Tags: android, beacon, kontakt.io

I am using th kontakt sdk along with radius beacon.
Here is the activity code:
http://pastebin.com/TQXdKwkX

But it isn't able to detect the beacon, what I see in logs is:

```
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
```

How can this be possibly fixed ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the beacon from kontakt or different vendor ?

Comment: In that case the beacons may be filtered based on their ID(Name) by the SDK and not shown.